# Jquery - Sortable did not work when div.load is called

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I have this issue that every time the div is loaded using div.load in the ajax success, the code for sortable will not work. Sortable will work again after the page is refreshed manually. What could be the possible solution for this?

```
$(document).on('click', '#add-song-tag', function() {

tag_id = $('#tags').val();

$.ajax({
    url: base_url + '/songtags/add_song_tag',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        song_info_id: song_info_id,
        tag_id: tag_id
    },
    success: function() {


        $('#category').load(window.location.href + ' #category');




        $('#modal-categories').trigger('change');
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
})
```

});

I have my code in the sortable.js like

```
$( function() {
$( "#sortable, #sortable1" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".draggable-group",
  start: function(event, ui){
    $(ui.item).width($('#sortable div').width());
  }
  // containment: "parent",
  // tolerance: "pointer"
}).disableSelection();
```

} );

and in the html it looks something like:

```
<?php if($selected_tag_for_m['category_id'] == $tempo_id):?>

                <div class="btn-group draggable-group">
                  <div>
                    <a href="" data-id="<?php echo $selected_tag_for_m['info_tag_id']?>"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg delete-a-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <div type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-color"><i class="fa fa-circle-o custom-text-blue"></i> <?php echo $selected_tag_for_m['tag_name'];?> </div>

                  <div type="button" class="btn btn-default custom-bgcolor-blue dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                    <span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                  </div>                
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="tempo">
                    <?php foreach($tempos as $tempo):?>
                    <li data-id="<?php echo $selected_tag_for_m['info_tag_id']?>"><a href="" data-id="<?php echo $tempo['tag_id']?>" class="songtaglist" ><?php echo $tempo['tag_name'];?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                  </ul>

                </div>

            <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: please post your code and also tell us what error do you get in browser log window.

Comment: I already edited my question @suomi-dev

Comment: what error do you see in browser console log window? could you press F12  and check there?

Comment: I am not getting any error @suomi-dev. On the div I have sortable lists but sortable will not work every time I load the div using load().

Comment: I think .load() is causing this problem what could be the other way of loading the content without page refresh and allow the custom js to work.

Comment: I dont think load is causing problem. Give that function a name and call the function after load. if that doesnt work then put alert or log at certain points in that function to see where it fails. also pls could you post the html or at least full working code?

Comment: I already edited the question. I have a div that contains the draggable elements. Also those elements are dynamically added depending on what database query returns. @suomi-dev

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to this by calling sortable.js script in body of the load function. The code looks like this:

```
$('#category').load(window.location.href + ' #category', function(){
                $.getScript(base_url + '/assets/js/sortable.js');                                               
            });
```